# C program stopped working when i tried changing some address values

Tags: c, memory, low-level

Have a look at my code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <limits.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {

typedef unsigned char byte;

byte *pointer;
byte b1=1;
byte b2=2;
int i1 =4;
int i2 =0x12345678;
byte b3=5;
byte b4=6;
byte b5=7;
byte b6=9;

//pointer = &b6;
pointer = (byte*)&i2;
printf("pointer  has value %p\n", pointer);
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
*pointer = 255;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
*pointer = 45;
printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
pointer =  pointer + 1;
*pointer = 34;

printf("the byte it points to contains %x\n", *pointer);
//printf("How big is int in this machine? %d\n", INT_MAX);
//insert code here ...
printf (" b1 (%p) = %x\n", &b1, b1);
printf (" b2 (%p) = %x\n", &b2, b2);
printf (" i1 (%p) = %d\n", &i1, i1);
printf (" i2 (%p) = %x\n", &i2, i2);
printf (" b3 (%p) = %x\n", &b3, b3);
printf (" b4 (%p) = %x\n", &b4, b4);
printf (" b5 (%p) = %x\n", &b5, b5);
printf (" b6 (%p) = %x\n", &b6, b6);

return 0;
}
```

The line saying ***pointer = 255;** , maybe 40th line , the compiler blows , or the code stops working , saying this 
[if I make , *pointer = 255 or *pointer = 254](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMRtm.jpg)

[and if I set any other values except this , my program works well i.e. 
 *pointer = 4556 or *pointer = 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2DAh.jpg)

Or in case of any other arbitrary values as well  , it runs without any blow . Please tell me about this behaviour of addresses.

*Source : Prof. Richard Buckland , I'm exploring all these due to his guidance.*

Comment: Your compiler didn't blow up. Your compiler is just fine. Your program is bad.

Comment: You are moving `pointer` value to addresses where you will inflict damage. Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Okay , thanks #Wane and #Art !! I was trying to explore how memory is used and where variables are stored in there . So , can you tell me what exactly is stored at that location , because it was just below an address where the variable _int i1_ was stored in the program .Is it the frame pointer's address or some critical section...?

Comment: Instead of risking breaking the machine, a safer way to explore how your local variables are stored is to initialise them with unique values and then print out bytes in hex, starting from the address of one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has nothing to do with this. You're trying to dereference and assign to an invalid pointer, to memory *you do not own*.

Doing just `++pointer; *pointer = <value>;` is dangerous as `pointer` points to a single value of type `int`, so `++pointer` (or adding any number except zero to it) is moving the pointer to some memory location you probably don't have permission to write to or even access. Hence the errors.

Comment: Okay , thanks !! I was trying to explore how memory is used and where variables are stored in there . So , can you tell me what exactly is stored at that location , because it was just below an address where the variable   _int i1_ was  stored in the program .Is it the  frame pointer's address or some critical section...?

Comment: @DivyanshuKushwaha, only the OS knows that. And the variables are not necessarily stored in contiguous memory exactly in the order of their declaration.

Comment: Actually, the compiler decides how code and static data are laid out for executables, and within each function what order locals are stored in on the stack. (OS X requires position-independent executables, so only relative order is guaranteed there, absolute is random).  @DivyanshuKushwaha: On all "normal" architectures (including x86), local variables are stored next to function return addresses, so it's totally normal for programs to crash if you write wrong values to memory.  Use a debugger if you want to explore the address space of your process.  (And/or on Linux, look at /proc/PID/maps).

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes , This explains a lot !!